# n-cumulative sum in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to get a n-cumulative sum of a vector in **tensorflow**.

```
import tensorflow as tf
input = tf.placeholder('float32', [None])
n = tf.placeholder('int32', ())

output = some_ops(input, n)
```

That is,

**INPUT**

`input` = [1, 3, 5, 8]

`n` = 2

**OUTPUT**

`output` = [1+3, 3+5, 5+8, 8]

For another example,

**INPUT**

`input` = [1,5,6,2,8,7,9]

`n` = 3

**OUTPUT**

`output` = [1+5+6, 5+6+2, 6+2+8, 2+8+7, 8+7+9, 7+9, 9]

What should I use for `some_ops`?

Answer (score 2):

[`tf.while_loop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/control_flow_operations#while_loop) is a handy function for such things. Here is the complete working code :

```
import tensorflow as tf
input = tf.placeholder('float32', [None])
n = tf.placeholder('int32', ())
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

tmp = tf.concat_v2([input,
                    tf.zeros(tf.expand_dims(n-1, 0),
                             dtype='float32')], axis=0)
i = tf.constant(0, dtype='int32')
output = tf.zeros([0], dtype='float32')

def body(i, output):
  return i + 1, tf.concat_v2([output,
                              tf.expand_dims(tf.reduce_sum(tmp[i:i+n]), 0)],
                             axis=0)

i, output = tf.while_loop(lambda i, _: i < tf.shape(input)[0],
                          body,
                          [i, output],
                          shape_invariants=[tf.TensorShape([]),
                                            tf.TensorShape([None])])

output.eval(feed_dict={n: 2, input:[1, 3, 5, 8]})
# array([  4.,   8.,  13.,   8.], dtype=float32)

output.eval(feed_dict={n: 3, input:[1,5,6,2,8,7,9]})
# array([ 12.,  13.,  16.,  17.,  24.,  16.,   9.], dtype=float32)
```